# AnimationDrawable or OnDraw for animated image

Tags: android

I would like to have 20 objects on the screen. Each object is animated and basically consists of 5 images frames. For example, lets say a house with smoke coming out. I was wondering which method to use (and why)

1- Animation Drawable where the images are defined in an animation set in an xml file. The animation is set to infinite

2- Custom view extending ImageView where I set the image needed at a certain frame in the OnDraw method and keep calling onDraw (or invalidated) at the end of the method

3- Some other method

I am inclined to use the first method for easiness but I am not sure of the proper way (or why I shouldnt use mine)

Thank you so much

Comment: Use `AnimationDrawable`. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, First one is easy and good approach. I made it before. Activity Initialization are as follows:

```
    ImageView imageViewAnimation;
    private AnimationDrawable independentAnimation;

    imageViewAnimation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAnimation);

        // set the animation drawable as background
        // here demo_logo_animation is an XML

        imageViewAnimation
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demo_logo_animation);
        // create an animation drawable using the background


        independentAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageViewAnimation
                .getBackground();

        // start the animation
        imageViewAnimation.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // fOR 2.3 DEVICES
                independentAnimation.start();
            }
        });
```

Place all images &  demo_logo_animation.xml in your **res/drawable** folder . The attribute  inside demo_logo_animation.xml, runs sequentially from top to bottom. so, place it carefully. Then demo_logo_animation.xml looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv001"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv003"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv006"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>


    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv009"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv012"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv015"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>


    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv018"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv021"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv024"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv027"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv030"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv033"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv036"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv039"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv042"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv045"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv048"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv051"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv054"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv057"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv060"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv063"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>




    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv066"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv069"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv072"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv075"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv078"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv081"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv084"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/itv087"
        android:duration="@string/log_in_duration"/>


</animation-list>
```

Comment: Thank you.. I assume the performance is the same between both options and I am not losing a lot